# Why do we need two way data binding in angular login forms?

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-ngmodel, angular-forms, 2-way-object-databinding

I am going through this code on github: https://github.com/linnovate/mean and there is something I do not understand. When you look at the [register form html code](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/src/app/auth/register/register.component.html) there is no two-way data binding and that I understand since there is no need for them.

My confusion starts when I look at the [login form html code](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/src/app/auth/login/login.component.html).

So my questions are:

1. Why is there two-way data binding on the login inputs? Is it to auto populate the input fields automatically using cookies? If so, how does the component communicate with the browser as I cannot see the code in the login.component.ts code?
2. If question 1. is true, why does the register form html code not have two-way data binding yet when I key in my email it automatically fills up the FullName input? How is this achieved without two-way data binding?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They just do that to avoid having to pull data themselves from the form using something like `form.controls.email.get('email').value`. With their binding, they directly have the value of the fields in `this.email` in the component, and thus can use the [simple line 22 in the ts file](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/src/app/auth/login/login.component.ts#L22):

```typescript
this.authService.login(this.email, this.password)
```

So, there is no cookies or server-side stuff involved. It is just frontend variable handling.